# Powershell: Command Passed To Start-Process Fails

Tags: powershell, start-process

First, i assign this string variable:

```
PS> $newpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client"
```

This works:

```
PS> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newpath, 'Machine')
```

This doesn't:

```
PS> Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit -noprofile -noninteractive -command [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newpath, 'Machine')" -Wait
```

The  second example returns:

```
At line:1 char:46
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS  ...
+                                              ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:47
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS  ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\Program' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... ient, 'Machine')
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

What am i doing wrong? I'm thinking it has something to do with strings, spaces, or quotes....

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Because your path contains spaces it must be quoted. This should work:

```
Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit -noprofile -noninteractive -command [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', '$newpath', 'Machine')" -Wait
```